# Confused about utf-8 and utf-16

Tags: character-encoding

If I set my content type in my website to be utf-8 does this mean I can't display other language characters? E.g. Japanese/Chinese

If I set it to utf-16 will it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can still use UTF-8. It only defines how many bytes it takes to represent your characters. For UTF-8 it takes 3, while it takes up only 2 bytes in UTF-16.

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 is a Unicode encoding which can encode ***all Unicode characters*** and uses a minimum of 8 bits to do so, and a maximum of 32 bits. UTF-16 is a Unicode encoding which can encode all Unicode characters and uses a minimum of 16 bits to do so or 32 if necessary.

All UTF-* encodings can encode all Unicode characters, they just use different means to do so.

Comment: Regarding utf-16, it is almost never used on the web and should not be expected to work. Internet software generally supports utf-8 and may or may not support other encodings.